# При вызове формы для загрузки файлов не успеваю выбрать файл - страница перезагружается

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, форма

Хочу стилизовать форму для загрузки файлов `input[type=file]`. Нашел изящное решение, которое привожу в коде. На html страничках все работает замечательно, но когда переношу на [сайт](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/22/your-profile/) (инпут с кнопкой обзор) возникает такой баг: при клике на кнопку всплывает системное меню, но не успеваешь даже выбрать файл или отводишь мышь от меню и страница внезапно перезагружается и пишет, что обновление. Как можно это исправить?
логин/пароль: demo

```html
<p>
  <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload_hidden" style="position: absolute; display: block; overflow: hidden; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;" onchange="document.getElementById('upload_visible').value = this.value;" />
  <input type="text" readonly="1" id="upload_visible" onclick="document.getElementById('upload_hidden').click();" />
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('upload_hidden').click();">Обзор</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Сделайте демо аккаунт, т.к. ссылка редиректит на форму входа.

Comment: @Neka сделал - добавил в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь `type="button"` к кнопке "обзор", должно помочь.